# VBA read file from specific string to end of file

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use Microsoft Scripting Runtime to open a text file, look for a specific string of text, and then copy that line and everything below it until the end of the file and write that to excel. I don't need it formatted by column, just want it to appear as it is in the file.. Below is the code that I'm trying to use but I think I've made a few errors.

```
Sub readFile()
    Dim sFileName As String

    sFileName = "C:\Users\Jamie\Desktop\REPORT.txt"
    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        With .OpenTextFile(sFileName, ForWriting)
            If Mid(sFileName, 3, 6) = "PALLET" Then
                .ReadAll
                Do Until .AtEndOfStream
                Loop
            End If
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Here is an example of the REPORT.TXT

```
RANDOM DATA THAT'S NOT NEEDEDRANDOM DATA THAT'S NOT NEEDED
RANDOM DATA THAT'S NOT NEEDED
RANDOM DATA THAT'S NOT NEEDED
RANDOM DATA THAT'S NOT NEEDEDRANDOM DATA THAT'S NOT NEEDEDRANDOM DATA THAT'S NOT NEEDED
RANDOM DATA THAT'S NOT NEEDED



     PALLET INFORMATION
=================================
UNDER 5 HRS     5
6 to 10 HRS     20
11 to 15 HRS    45
OVER 20 HRS     12
=================================

Report Generated on 2/12/19 by IBM z/OS JBL.9897992
```

Comment: How big is the file? Unless it's absurdly large, it would probably be easier to just read the whole thing into a `String` and *then* parse the text you need out.

Comment: Usually over 70,000 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your code refactored to achieve what you want.  It mainly shows how to use the `FileSystemObject` to read text files.  I suspect you'll want to make changes once you get to grips with reading the file data, to make placing the data into the sheet easier.

Version 1 - if file is small enough to read into a single string

```
Sub readFile()
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim FileData As String
    Dim PalletData As String
    Dim idx As Long
    Dim LocationToPlaceData As Range

    sFileName = "C:\Data\Temp\Report.txt" '"C:\Users\Jamie\Desktop\REPORT.txt"
    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        With .OpenTextFile(sFileName, ForReading)
            FileData = .ReadAll
            .Close
        End With
    End With
    idx = InStr(FileData, "PALLET")
    If idx > 0 Then
        PalletData = Mid$(FileData, idx)
        'get location to place data - update to suit your needs
        Set LocationToPlaceData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

        'Place Data in a single cell
        LocationToPlaceData = PalletData
    End If
End Sub
```

Version 2 - if file is too big to read into a single string.

```
Sub readFile2()
    Dim sFileName As String
    Dim FileLine As String
    Dim PalletData As String
    Dim idx As Long
    Dim LocationToPlaceData As Range

    sFileName = "C:\Data\Temp\Report.txt" '"C:\Users\Jamie\Desktop\REPORT.txt"
    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        With .OpenTextFile(sFileName, ForReading)
            Do Until .AtEndOfStream
                FileLine = .ReadLine
                idx = InStr(FileLine, "PALLET")
                If idx > 0 Then
                    PalletData = Mid$(FileLine, idx)
                    Do Until .AtEndOfStream
                        PalletData = PalletData & vbCrLf & .ReadLine
                    Loop
                End If
            Loop
            .Close
        End With
    End With

    'get location to place data - update to suit your needs
    Set LocationToPlaceData = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")

    'Place Data in a single cell
    LocationToPlaceData = PalletData
End Sub
```